# Sorting with special format to numbers in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

So while using datatables https://datatables.net/ i want to format currency so it shows like $1B (one billion), $1M (one million) and $1K (one thousand) but the thing is that when sorting this it's the same 1M as 1B, so if i have 2M and 1B, 2 million will be more than 1 billion, is there any possibility to sort using a format like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter [File size](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/file-size) sorting plugin to produce the code below:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['currency-abbr-pre'] = function ( data ) {
    var matches = data.match( /^\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([a-z]+)/i );
    var multipliers = {
        k: 1000,
        m: 1000000,
        b: 1000000000
    };

    if (matches) {
        var multiplier = multipliers[matches[2].toLowerCase()];
        return parseFloat( matches[1] ) * multiplier;
    } else {
        return -1;
    };
};

$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            { type: 'currency-abbr', targets: 1 }
        ]    
    });
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/4bonz09c/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: i found a more simple solution, i've added the tag data-sort to <td> so datatables will sort by that value, but thanks for the answer

Comment: @Janva, yes, that would work too. I didn't know you had original values as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td data-sort="1000">1B</td>
<td data-sort="10">10M</td>
```

Comment: Your intent is good but I recommend to improve the answer. Like explaining why the code you post works. For example, adding a simple text explaining a bit of what's your reasoning: "Use one unit for the sort in the `data-sort` attribute and display formatted to the user"

Comment: This isn't working for me in Datatables :/